# How to add multiple value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add value with attribute name="data[]" and put result to input with attribute `name="total_data"`?

When type input in data 1, data 2 etc, the result will appear in total data with additional.
If I type value 1 in data 1 and type value 3 in data 2, total data will show value 4. How to do that?

```html
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 1" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 2" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 3" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 4" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 5" /><br><br>
<input name="total_data" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="Total Data" />
```

Comment: [Sum a list of text boxes in jQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/2171597) and [jQuery calculate sum of values in all text fields](//stackoverflow.com/q/2417553)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```js
$('input[name="data[]"]').change(function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('input[name="data[]"]').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() !==''){
        total +=parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    
  });
  $('input[name="total_data"]').val(total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 1" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 2" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 3" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 4" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 5" /><br><br>
<input name="total_data" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="Total Data" />
```

Note:- you can use `keyup()` also instead of `change()`.

Comment: thanks, thats working very well.. I replace change function to keyup function

Comment: @silviazulinka  yes you can do that. I have just posted one way to do this. glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way:

```js
$('.input-data').change(function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-data');
    var total = 0;
    inputs.forEach(function(node, index){
        if(node.value != ""){
            total += parseInt(node.value);
        }
    });
    document.getElementsByClassName('input-data-total')[0].value = total;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 1" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 2" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 3" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 4" /><br><br>
<input name="data[]" type="number" class="input-data" value="" placeholder="data 5" /><br><br>
<input name="total_data" type="text" class="input-data-total" value="" placeholder="Total Data" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a jquery function as below and call this function onchange event of data[] inputs. Code is written from memory and not tested

```
function doTotal(){
    var total=0;
    $("input[name='data[]']").each(function(){
       total+=$(this).val(); 
    });

    $("input [name='totalData']").val(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery documentaion [kaypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) you can do it by every key press.

```
$('input[name="data[]"]').keypress(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[name="data[]"]').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() !==''){
        sum +=parseInt($(this).val());
      }

  });
  $('input[name="total_data"]').val(sum);

});
```